# How to identify connection timed out status using PQstatus in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to add connect_timeout parameter to `PQconnectdb()`. How could i differentiate between connection timeout and all other failure scenarios? The `PQstatus(conn)` followed by `PQconnectdb` only reveals two states `CONNECTION_OK` or `CONNECTION_BAD`. How to deduce connection timed out from `CONNECTION_BAD`?

PS: Expecting solution excluding `PQconnectStart` and `PQconnectPoll`.